# Topological space that is not sequential and not $T_0$

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

Construct an example of a topological space $(X,T)$ that is not sequential and is not $T_0$.

Preferably the example should not involve a pseudometric, a finite set $X$, or the trivial topology $\{X, \emptyset\}$

Comment: Disjoint union of a non-sequential space with a space that's not $T_0$?

Comment: @silvascientist: Or the product.

Comment: So whose idea was it to undelete this post?

Comment: I do not know how to interpret your earlier comment. Do you prefer for your post to be deleted or undeleted?

Comment: @quid Tell me something: do you think there is anything good about this post or is it all bad, ignoring the fact that it was closed and deleted?  I understand why it was closed and deleted the first time, but I don't get why it was undeleted and "re-deleted" several times.

Comment: @cpiegore You are aware that you can see who voted to delete/undelete [in the revision history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1422534/revisions), right?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, but this doesn't answer my real question: is my post in any way a good question for this site?  Because it was closed and deleted, I am somewhat inclined to believe the answer is NO.

Comment: @cpiegore I will leave judging whether it is good question to others. The users who voted to close your post left you a big banner [with a link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) explaining how the question could be improved. But clearly [at least the answerer thinks](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422534/topological-space-that-is-not-sequential-and-not-t-0#comment3921258_1422538) that it would be useful to keep this post on the site.

Comment: The question is rather terse and imposes restrictions that could come off as arbitrary.  A better way to ask this would be to include examples you seem to know about and ask for complementary ones.  I do not like the answer (even though I did not yet vote on it). The first comment is nice though. In total, I would not call this is a good thread. Don't get me wrong, there are plenty of worse ones around. The reason your post receives  continued attention is that it found its way into a moderation thread http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21319

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y=\omega_1+1$ with the order topology $\tau'$, and let $p$ be a point not in $Y$. Let $X=Y\cup\{p\}$, and let

$$\tau=\{U\in\tau':0\notin U\}\cup\big\{U\cup\{p\}:0\in U\in\tau'\big\}\;$$

then $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is not $T_0$, because every open set contains either both or neither of the points $0$ and $p$, and it’s not sequential, because $X\setminus\{\omega_1\}$ is a sequentially closed set that is not closed.

**Added:** In case you’re not familiar with ordinals and their topology, here’s a simpler variant of the same basic idea. Let $Y$ be an uncountable set, $y_0$ and $y_1$ distinct points of $y$, and $p$ a point not in $Y$. Let $X=Y\cup\{p\}$, $\mathscr{U}=\wp(Y\setminus\{y_0,y_1\})$, and $\mathscr{V}=\big\{U\cup\{y_0,y_1\}:U\in\mathscr{U}\big\}$. Finally, let

$$\tau=\mathscr{U}\cup\mathscr{V}\cup\{X\setminus C:C\in\mathscr{U}\cup\mathscr{V}\text{ and }C\text{ is countable}\}\;;$$

then $\tau$ is a topology on $X$. Every member of $\tau$ contains either both or neither of the points $y_0$ and $y_1$, so $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is not $T_0$. $Y$ is sequentially closed, since the convergent sequences in $Y$ are those that are eventually constant or eventually in the set $\{y_0,y_1\}$, but $p\in\operatorname{cl}_XY$, so $Y$ is not closed in $X$.

Comment: If I understand the solution correctly, isn't the basic idea simply taking *any* space $Y$ which is not sequential and then removing $T_0$-property by "doubling" one point. (I.e., adding a new point $p$ and creating neighborhood of this point from some $y\in Y$ simply by using both these points in all open sets of the original space containing $y$)?

Comment: @Martin: Yes. I don’t remember whether I consciously realized that at the time and wanted to stick with concrete examples, or whether I didn’t consciously notice the generalization. I’m pretty sure that I doubled one of the isolated points in the second example (rather than the limit point) because that made it extremely easy to see why $Y$ is sequentially closed.