# Example of a topological space which is neither sequential nor $T_0$

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

> What would be examples of topological spaces that are neither [sequential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space) nor [$T_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space)?

[$\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%7E%24T_0%24%2B%7ESequential) does not have an example of such space.

I have seen some examples of non-sequential spaces. [Arens-Fort space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arens%E2%80%93Fort_space)
is mentioned in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100380/is-a-net-stronger-than-a-transfinite-sequence-for-characterizing-topology). Another space mentioned there is the [Stone-Čech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) $\beta\mathbb N$. However, both of them are Hausdorff.

From non-Hausdorff spaces I was able to find the [cocountable topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountable_topology) on an uncountable set. However, it is still a $T_1$-space.

So, the question remains of giving simple examples of non-sequential spaces which are not $T_0$.

Comment: The reason for posting this was the delete-undelete war on [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422534/topological-space-that-is-not-sequential-and-not-t-0). (See also [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21319).) This also means that I know the answer - I have seen it on the deleted post. The repeated deletion and undeletion suggests that some users consider this question useful and some do not. I hope that this version of the question has the better form than the original one. Perhaps in this way everybody is satisfied.

Comment: Can't you just pick a point $x_0$ that is in your favourite non-sequential space $X$ and a point $x_1$ that is not and then topologise the disjoint union $Y = X \sqcup \{x_1\}$, by taking $A\subseteq Y$ to be open if  $A \cap X$ is open in $X$ and either (1)  $x_0 \not\in A$ or (2) $\{x_0, x_1\} \subseteq A$? Then every open subset of $Y$ that contains $x_0$ also contains $x_1$, so $Y$ is not $T_0$, while a sequentially open subset of $X$ that is not open will still by sequentially open but not open in $Y$.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, that seems like a rather natural way to construct such an example. In fact, this is precisely the space described in Brian M. Scott's answer in the paragraph about "a very simple machine".

Comment: Indeed: I was typing my comment while Brian was typing his answer,

Comment: @MartinSleziak Well played.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, please take a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2026428/what-is-second-bartlett-identity#comment4205268_2026428) and let me know what you think of it. (I enjoy playing the detective!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a very elementary example let $Y$ be an uncountable set, $y_0$ and $y_1$ distinct points of $y$, and $p$ a point not in $Y$. Let $X=Y\cup\{p\}$, $\mathscr{U}=\wp(Y\setminus\{y_0,y_1\})$, and $\mathscr{V}=\big\{U\cup\{y_0,y_1\}:U\in\mathscr{U}\big\}$. Finally, let

$$\tau=\mathscr{U}\cup\mathscr{V}\cup\{X\setminus C:C\in\mathscr{U}\cup\mathscr{V}\text{ and }C\text{ is countable}\}\;;$$

then $\tau$ is a topology on $X$. Every member of $\tau$ contains either both or neither of the points $y_0$ and $y_1$, so $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is not $T_0$. $Y$ is sequentially closed, since the convergent sequences in $Y$ are those that are eventually constant or eventually in the set $\{y_0,y_1\}$, but $p\in\operatorname{cl}_XY$, so $Y$ is not closed in $X$.

One that fails to be sequential but still has non-trivial convergent sequences can be obtained by letting $Y=\omega_1+1$ with the order topology $\tau'$ and $p$ be a point not in $Y$. Let $X=Y\cup\{p\}$, and let

$$\tau=\{U\in\tau':0\notin U\}\cup\big\{U\cup\{p\}:0\in U\in\tau'\big\}\;$$

then $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is not $T_0$, because every open set contains either both or neither of the points $0$ and $p$, and it’s not sequential, because $X\setminus\{\omega_1\}$ is a sequentially closed set that is not closed.

Each of these is the result of applying a very simple ‘machine’ to an arbitrary non-sequential space $\langle Y,\tau\rangle$. Fix some $y_0\in Y$, let $Z=\{0,1\}$ have the indiscete topology, and let $X=(Y\times Z)/{\sim}$, where $\langle y_1,z_0\rangle\sim\langle y_2,z_1\rangle$ if and only if either $\langle y_1,z_0\rangle=\langle y_2,z_1\rangle$, or $y_1=y_2\ne y_0$. This simply doubles the point $y_0$, turning it into two distinct points with identical nbhds in $X$, in such a way that $Y$ is the [Kolmogorov quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space#The_Kolmogorov_quotient) of $X$.

In fact it is true in general that if $X$ is non-sequential, then the Kolmogorov quotient $Y$ of $X$ is non-sequential, so every example of a non-sequential, non-$T_0$ space can be obtained by ‘fattening up’ a $T_0$ non-sequential space, albeit not necessarily at just one point.