# Proof of the unbiasedness of an estimate obtained by gradient search

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

As the solution to an MLE problem cannot be obtained analytically, I apply gradient search to find the solution $\hat{\theta}$ to satisfies 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{y}\mid\theta)}{\partial \theta} = 0
\end{align}
Without the expression of $\hat{\theta}$, how can I prove that 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}) = \theta
\end{align}
Are there any standard methods?

Comment: Is $\hat\theta$ guaranteed to be unbiased for $\theta$?

Comment: Numerically yes, by averaging $\hat{\theta}$, it does converge to $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

the question appears vague...so also the answer cannot be at top

by the way, in some situation, the [Bartlett Identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2026428/what-is-second-bartlett-identity) can helps

First Bartlett Identity: $\mathbb{E}[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}l(\theta;\mathbf{x})]=0$

In fact can happens that in the expression of the score you can find the expression of $\hat{\theta}$ so, using the above mentioned identity perhaps you can derive the expected value  you are looking for

If you are interested in, I can think at a particular exercise to better explain what I am saying.

***EXAMPLE, as requested***

Let's have a random sample $(X_1,...,X_n)$ from the following density, $\theta, x >0$

$f(x;\theta)=\sqrt{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}}x^{-\frac{3}{2}}e^{\frac{-\theta}{2}\frac{(x-1)^2}{x}}$

Suppose to have the following estimator for $\frac{1}{\theta}$:

$T=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i\frac{(x_i-1)^2}{x_i}$

Tell if T is unbiased for $\frac{1}{\theta}$ that's mean: prove that

$\mathbb{E}[T]=\frac{1}{\theta}$

***SOLUTION***

1) calculate the likeihood

2) take the log

3) derive with respect to $\theta$ (this is the score) finding

$Score(\theta)=\frac{n}{2\theta}-\frac{nT}{2}$

Applying the first Bartlett identity you get

$\mathbb{E}[\frac{n}{2\theta}-\frac{nT}{2}]=0$

That's mean

$\frac{n}{2\theta}=\frac{n}{2}\mathbb{E}[T]$

that is also

$\mathbb{E}[T]=\frac{1}{\theta}$

Comment: Thanks for bringing Bartlett Identity to me. Could you please give me some examples? I cannot figure it out based on the information from Wikipedia.

Comment: @RichardSEU : now you've got it