# Mean squared error of 1/sample mean

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation, mean-square-error

Let $n$ be the estimator defined by:
$$
n = \frac{1}{\text{sample mean}}
$$

What is the mean squared error of the n estimator?

I assume there is no bias since the sample mean is an unbiased estimator.

Is this correct?
$$
MSE(n) = \operatorname{Var}(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Bigl(\frac{1}{x_{i}} - \frac{1}{x_\text{sample mean}}\Bigr)^{2}
$$

Comment: Before you can define bias and MSE you must first clarify, what $\frac{1}{samplemean}$ is an estimator of. For instance it could be an estimator of $\frac{1}{\mu}$ in which case it is probably biased since usually $\frac{1}{E[X]} \neq E[\frac{1}{X}]$.

Answer (score 1):

No.

1. if $\overline{X}_n$ is unbiased, say $\mathbb{E}[\overline{X}_n]=g(\theta)$ it is wellknown that $\frac{1}{\overline{X}_n}$ is biased (this is [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)).
2. To calculate mean, variance, and MSE of $\frac{1}{\overline{X}_n}=\frac{n}{\sum_i X_i}$ you have to know the distribution on $\sum_i X_i$
3. Sometimes mean and variance  $\frac{1}{\overline{X}_n}=\frac{n}{\sum_i X_i}$ can be derived with some brainstomings on the score of the model (for example using [Bartlett's identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2026428/what-is-second-bartlett-identity))